# How can I pass header and parameter with HttpClient in .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, dotnet-httpclient, restsharp

This is my code using the RestSharp library:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://example.com/api");
client.Timeout = -1;

var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer token...");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
request.AddParameter("text/plain", "{{\"post\":{{\"contact\":{{\"isActive\":true,\"phone\":\"99999999\"}}", ParameterType.RequestBody);

IRestResponse response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
// Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
// var res = response.Content;
```

How can I convert it to `HttpClient` using best practices?

Comment: It is not a http client , please fix the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
var client = new HttpClient()
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri("https://example.com"),
    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5) //default is 90 seconds
};

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer token...");
var body = new StringContent("{{\"post\":{{\"contact\":{{\"isActive\":true,\"phone\":\"99999999\"}}",Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain");

var response = await client.PostAsync("api", body);

var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

And for using the `HttpClient` in the right way I highly recommend to see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests).

Comment: I would recommend specifying the content type in the `StringContent` constructor rather than adding it as a header.

Comment: Yes you are  right answer updated.